# comma when addressing a person

Tags: punctuation, commas

If I am showing someone a picture of my nephew, and his name is Bob, should I say:
'This is my nephew Bob', without a comma, or:
'This is my nephew, Bob'. with the comma. 
Doesn't the comma lend the impression that I'm talking to Bob?

Answer (score 1):

The comma changes the meaning.

> This is my nephew Bob.

would be where you are introducing your nephew Bob to someone. In this sense, a comma would not be used.

> This is my nephew, Bob.

Here you are talking to Bob, and introducing your nephew. In this sense, Bob is not your nephew.
If you say the latter one with a pause at the comma, this may make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Nouns in apposition are usually separated by a comma, so using the comma need not imply that you are talking to Bob. Language is very flexible, and the interpretation of any short piece of text is always made with regard to the context. If it is clear in the discourse that you are actually talking to Bob, then this would be the interpretation, comma or not. And the other alternative would hold in exactly the same way.